# How to Install Linux Bootloader to root

Tags: bootloader, dual-boot

I want to install Ubuntu 11.10 but its bootloader should be installed to linux root and not to MBR because i want Windows 7, Mac OSX Lion and Ubuntu 11.10 with Chameleon Bootloader as default Loader.

Comment: In the installation wizard chose advanced mode , in that mode you can see the option for where the grub is to be installed ,chose your linux partion and press next

Comment: http://www.osx86.net/guides-tutorials/10747-guide-chameleon-bootloader-basics.html

Answer (score 3):

[Tachyons](https://askubuntu.com/users/39372/tachyons) answered this in [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119415/how-to-install-linux-bootloader-to-root#comment141942_119415):

> In the installation wizard chose advanced mode , in that mode you can
>   see the option for where the grub is to be installed ,chose your linux
>   partion and press next